# Decrypting APDU response from iPhone6

Tags: android, nfc, apdu, emv, applepay

I transmitted the following APDU command, from an android app, in my android phone,

> send: `00 A4 04 00 07 A0 00 00 00 03 10 10 00`

to an iPhone 6 through NFC and got the following response,

> resp: `6F 39 84 07 A0 00 00 00 03 10 10 A5 2E 9F 38 1B 9F 66 04 9F 02 06 9F 03 06 9F 1A 02 95 05 5F 2A 02 9A 03 9C 01 9F 37 04 9F 4E 14 BF 0C 0D 9F 4D 02 14 01 9F 5A 05 11 08 40 08 40 90 00`

Now, I've been trying to decrypt this using various sources, but the confusing part is to understand, whether this is the PKPaymenttoken data (which we receive in apple pay response) or is it just the encrypted card data from the passbook of iPhone 6.

I compared this result with the response that I got from PassKit- framework's-> paymentAuthorizationViewController method's-> payment.token string, both are completely different. So  I guess its not the token response for apple pay. My concerns are,

1. Is this the encrypted card data itself? Can I decrypt it directly to get the card details? (After all, will Apple give out the card details that easily?)
2. My ultimate requirement is to accept payment through NFC in an Android phone from an iPhone6. So is my APDU request the correct one to obtain card data from iPhone6 (Passbook)?

Any thought is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: can you please tell me the reason for down vote?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried with the help of this link

https://github.com/devnied/EMV-NFC-Paycard-Enrollment

It really works. It gives device account number directly from the iPhone. No decryption needed to get this device account number.

**How to use this lib**

Download the library from [this](https://github.com/devnied/EMV-NFC-Paycard-Enrollment) link

Use the code below

```
IProvider prov = new YourProvider();
// Create parser (true for contactless false otherwise)
EMVParser parser = new EMVParser(prov, true);
// Read card
EMVCard card = parser.readEmvCard();
```

You will get the card details in **card** object.

**To answer your two major questions**

1. This is just a response for APDU command, if you use the library I've mentioned, you will directly get the card details required for payment via any gateways.
2. The first answer is also the answer for your second question, you can read the iphone 6 from an android phone using the library. so just two steps Integrate the library -> get the card details -> forward to payment gateway. By this method, you need not send any private keys to the gateways, just send the card details like you do for normal card payment processing.

Comment: You already saved my code, thanks a lot. I already verified your answer as the right one, No matter I'll do that 100times. I couldn't move past the decryption of APDU command, this library works like a jinx. Thanks a lot man.

Answer (score 3):

Its not encrypted data, it just FCI information

APDU send by you:
 **00 A4 04 00 07 A0 00 00 00 03 10 10 00**.
P1=0x04 means you are selecting MF by DF name and P2=0x00 means returns FCI information.

Your response **6F 39 84 07 A0 00 00 00 03 10 10 A5 2E 9F 38 1B 9F 66 04 9F 02 06 9F 03 06 9F 1A 02 95 05 5F 2A 02 9A 03 9C 01 9F 37 04 9F 4E 14 BF 0C 0D 9F 4D 02 14 01 9F 5A 05 11 08 40 08 40 90 00**

Your response description are as follows:
6F->its FCI templates(i.e. set of control parameters and management data).
39->6F tag length, these bytes are 6F tag data **84 07 A0 00 00 00 03 10 10 A5 2E 9F 38 1B 9F 66 04 9F 02 06 9F 03 06 9F 1A 02 95 05 5F 2A 02 9A 03 9C 01 9F 37 04 9F 4E 14 BF 0C 0D 9F 4D 02 14 01 9F 5A 05 11 08 40 08 40 90 00**
84 means Tag for DF name
07 is the Lengths
A0 00 00 00 03 10 10 data values i.e. DF name
A5 is the Tag for Proprietary information encoded in BER-TLV
2E is the Length
9F 38 1B 9F 66 04 9F 02 06 9F 03 06 9F 1A 02 95 05 5F 2A 02 9A 03 9C 01 9F 37 04 9F 4E 14 BF 0C 0D 9F 4D 02 14 01 9F 5A 05 11 08 40 08 40 90 00->A5 tag values

Comment: Thanks for the help, but is there any other specific commands to access the card data from the iphone6? I am new to this concept, sorry if I am not clear with the question
>`9F 38 1B 9F 66 04 9F 02 06 9F 03 06 9F 1A 02 95 05 5F 2A 02 9A 03 9C 01 9F 37 04 9F 4E 14 BF 0C 0D 9F 4D 02 14 01 9F 5A 05 11 08 40 08 40 90 00->A5 tag values`
This tag has some sub-tags, does it contain any real data or is this APDU response just a information snippet?

Comment: Actually, I was the one who asked the question, so just thought of getting more info from @anand.

Answer (score 3):

### Is this the encrypted card data itself? Can I decrypt it directly to get the card details?

No and no. As [Anand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1636022/anand) correctly pointed out in their answer, this is the FCI template returned in response to your SELECT (by AID/DF name) command concatenated with the status word `9000` (indicating success).

The FCI template is a TLV (tag-length-value) encoded data structure following basic encoding rules (BER). So your FCI

```
6F 39 84 07 A0 00 00 00 03 10 10 A5 2E 9F 38 1B 9F 66 04 9F 02 06 9F 03 06 9F 1A 02 95 05 5F 2A 02 9A 03 9C 01 9F 37 04 9F 4E 14 BF 0C 0D 9F 4D 02 14 01 9F 5A 05 11 08 40 08 40
```

decodes to (see http://www.emvlab.org/tlvutils/):

```
6F [39]   File Control Information (FCI) Template
    84 [07]   Dedicated File (DF) Name
        A0000000031010    (full AID of the application that you just selected)
    A5 [2E]   File Control Information (FCI) Proprietary Template
        9F38 [1B]   Processing Options Data Object List (PDOL)
            9F66 04
            9F02 06
            9F03 06
            9F1A 02
            95 05
            5F2A 02
            9A 03
            9C 01
            9F37 04
            9F4E 14
    BF0C [0D]   File Control Information (FCI) Issuer Discretionary Data
        9F4D [02]   Log Entry
            1401    (Transaction log file with at most 1 record is available at SFI 0x14)
        9F5A [05]   Application Program Identifier (Program ID)
            1108400840
```

### My ultimate requirement is to accept payment [...]. So is my APDU request the correct one to obtain card data from iPhone6?

Partially, yes. After application selection, you will need to perform an EMV payment transaction (following the EMV specifications for contactless payment systems, you can get them form http://www.emvco.com/). However, be aware that this is not as easy as getting some "card data". You will need to retrieve some static card data from the contactless "card" (i.e. iPhone). In addition you will also need to let the iPhone generate some dynamic transaction cryptogram/transaction authorization code. You can then use this data to clear the transaction.

Comment: > `Processing Options Data Object List (PDOL)` 

While using BP_Tools EMV decryptor, this particular tag when expanded, had amount, transaction type, country code and few more details which are the same as that of PKPayment token response.

So that's why I got that second question, if its just FCI details, what does all those tag names mean? Is it like a label that says these contents are all accessible from the "Contactless card/iPhone" or is it file itself, waiting to be decrypted? Sorry if I am wrong!

Comment: The PDOL contains a list of data objects that you need to provide to the application in order to generate the dynamic transaction cryptogram/transaction authorization code. Elaborating how to perform EMV payment transactions would certainly be way to broad for SO, that's why I suggest that you start by looking into the EMV payment specifications (see my answer "*After application selection, you will need to perform an EMV payment transaction (following the EMV specifications for contactless payment systems, you can get them form http://www.emvco.com/).*")

Comment: That's great, I'll start looking into emvco.com. Can you please explain what you meant by the term **application selection** in the sentence, "After application selection, you will need to perform an EMV payment transaction".

Comment: The APDU command that you sent to the card/iPhone. That's a SELECT (by AID/DF name) APDU that performs application selection of the VISA credit/debit card EMV payment application: CLA=00, INS=A4 (SELECT), P1=04 (by DF name), P2=00, Lc=07, DATA=A0000000031010 (AID/DF name of application: VISA credit/debit), Le=00

Comment: Okay. That helps really, I'll try and move further into the document.Cheers